# Grafana: can it graph the change in two measurements?

Tags: graph, grafana

I'm trying to find a way to measure the delta of two measurements in a Grafana graph. For example, I have chart one with a plotted point 1 equal to 100 and five minutes later point 2 is 75, the second chart would plot a value of -25...the delta over five minutes from chart one. Or +25 would work for my purposes just as well.

Are there instructions on how to do that?

The database is InfluxDB. Grafana version 3.02.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using the `difference()` function which calculates the delta between two points.

An InfluxDB query could be:

`SELECT difference(last("db_size_bytes")) FROM ...`

Ref: [InfluxDB Difference function](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.6/query_language/functions/#difference)